# Why BitmapData has been categorized simply as Bitmap.data?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

However, i less often use bitmap classes. But noticing the existence of these two classes ( Bitmap and BitmapData ) wonders me.. why BitmapData could simply be Bitmap.getData or Bitmap.data ?

Any clue ?

Thanks
Vishwas

Comment: Because Bitmap is DisplayObject , BitmapData is encoded image , so even if You load .jpg it must be parsed  . And if You like to create few Bitmaps , You can pin to each same BitmapData . And more - in BitmapData You can operate on pixels , how would You do this on ByteArray ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Bitmap` is a visual representation of `BitmapData`. It inherits from `DisplayObject` meaning that it has properties for positioning such as `x` and `y` and for size such as `width` and `height` among other things.

`BitmapData` holds a large amount of properties and methods strictly related to the representation of an image rather than the visible image itself. You can work with `BitmapData` a lot before actually rendering what it represents, if at all. It wouldn't make sense to merge the two classes. Here are some reasons:

1. Multiple instances of Bitmap can reference a single instance of BitmapData, saving a lot of memory and increasing performance. In my game engine there is only ever one instance of Bitmap in the DisplayList, but all of the game entities have their own reference to a piece of BitmapData that will act as it's visuals.
2. I don't want to have to create an entire Bitmap instance (which is large) just to work with its BitmapData. It makes far more sense to just have a significantly lighter weight class do the work you need.
3. A single instance of Bitmap can take portions information from an unlimited amount of BitmapData instances and then render them. It wouldn't seem logic for Bitmap and BitmapData to be one class with this in mind because it would seem from an OOP point of view that this single class should only represent a single graphic.
4. They just aren't the same thing. They can work without each other and have practical and common uses doing so.

There are many more reasons but those are just a few.

Comment: Why didn't you accept the edit? FYI, correct usage of *number* and *amount* is one of my pet peeves ;) http://www.writing.com/main/books/entry_id/318060

Answer (score 1):

`BitmapData` is the core representation of the image data; 4 channels in the image per pixel: alpha, red, green and blue. Using this, you can manipulate every pixel.

The `Bitmap` class is a sub-class of `DisplayObject`, it's what is used to render the bitmap data inside the display list.